# NumPy array sum reduce

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sum, reduce

I have a numpy array with three columns of the form:

```
x1 y1 f1


x2 y2 f2


...

xn yn fn
```

The (x,y) pairs may repeat. I would need another array such that each (x,y) pair appears once and the corresponding third column is the sum of all the f values that appeared next to (x,y).

For example, the array

```
1 2 4.0

1 1 5.0

1 2 3.0

0 1 9.0
```

would give

```
0 1 9.0

1 1 5.0

1 2 7.0
```

The order of rows is not relevant. What is the fastest way to do this in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at `at`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html

Comment: I would use a pandas dataframe

Comment: @hpaulj, this works nicely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one approach to solve it -

```
import numpy as np

# Input array
A = np.array([[1,2,4.0],
             [1,1,5.0],
             [1,2,3.0],
             [0,1,9.0]])

# Extract xy columns            
xy = A[:,0:2]

# Perform lex sort and get the sorted indices and xy pairs
sorted_idx = np.lexsort(xy.T)
sorted_xy =  xy[sorted_idx,:]

# Differentiation along rows for sorted array
df1 = np.diff(sorted_xy,axis=0)
df2 = np.append([True],np.any(df1!=0,1),0)
# OR df2 = np.append([True],np.logical_or(df1[:,0]!=0,df1[:,1]!=0),0)
# OR df2 = np.append([True],np.dot(df1!=0,[True,True]),0)

# Get unique sorted labels
sorted_labels = df2.cumsum(0)-1

# Get labels
labels = np.zeros_like(sorted_idx)
labels[sorted_idx] = sorted_labels

# Get unique indices
unq_idx  = sorted_idx[df2]

# Get counts and unique rows and setup output array
counts = np.bincount(labels, weights=A[:,2])
unq_rows = xy[unq_idx,:]
out = np.append(unq_rows,counts.ravel()[:,None],1)
```

Input & Output -

```
In [169]: A
Out[169]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  9.]])

In [170]: out
Out[170]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  7.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hpaulj, finally found the simplest solution. If d contains the 3-column data:

```
ind =d[0:2].astype(int)
x = zeros(shape=(N,N))
add.at(x,list(ind),d[2])
```

This solution assumes that the (x,y) indices in the first two columns are integer and smaller than N. This is what I need and should have mentioned in the post.

Edit: Note that the above solution produces a sparse matrix with the sum values at position (x,y) within the matrix.

Comment: Would be interesting to see some runtime tests, maybe?

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried it with the input listed in the question and got some other unexpected values. I assumed `N = 3` for that.

Comment: This does not produce anything near the output in the question. It produces a sparse matrix with the sums at the x, y coordinates.

Comment: @Colt45, that is correct. From the sparse matrix however it is easy to recover the desired output form. Probably it is not optimal for large N though. I completely admit that my question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly easily done in Python:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,4.0],
                [1,1,5.0],
                [1,2,3.0],
                [0,1,9.0]])
d={}                
for x, y, z in arr:
    d.setdefault((x,y), 0)
    d[x,y]+=z     

>>> d
{(1.0, 2.0): 7.0, (0.0, 1.0): 9.0, (1.0, 1.0): 5.0}
```

Then translate back to numpy:

```
>>> np.array([[x,y,d[(x,y)]] for x,y in d.keys()]) 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  5.]])
```

Comment: nice solution with dictionaries, however it involves a bunch of for loops

Answer (score 0):

If you have `scipy`, the sparse module does this kind of addition - again for an array where the 1st 2 columns are integers - ie. indexes.

```
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.csr_matrix((d[:,0], (d[:,1],d[:,2])))
M = M.tocoo() # there may be a short cut to this csr coo round trip
x = np.column_stack([M.row, M.col, M.data]) # needs testing
```

For convenience in constructing certain kinds of linear algebra matrices, the `csr` sparse array format sums values with duplicate indices.  It's implemented in compiled code so should be fairly fast.  But putting the data into `M` and taking it back out might slow it down.

(ps. I haven't tested this script since I'm writing this on a machine without `scipy`).